# LEFT JOIN using _PARTITIONDATE

Tags: join, google-bigquery, left-join

I'm currently using StandardSQL in BigQuery, I tried to join two sets of table one of which is a pseudo-column table partitioned by day.

I tried to use this query below:

```
SELECT 
        DISTINCT DATE(create_time) AS date,
        user_id,
        city_name,
        transaction_id,
        price

FROM 
        table_1 a

LEFT JOIN (SELECT user_id, city_name FROM table_2) b 
        ON (a.user_id = b.user_id AND DATE(create_time) = _PARTITIONDATE)
```

I've tried this kind of JOIN (using _PARTITIONDATE) and worked out, but for this particular query I got an error message:

`Unrecognized name: _PARTITIONDATE`

Can anyone tell me why this happened, and how could I solve this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that you are not selecting the `_PARTITIONDATE` field from `table_2` when joining it so it can't recognize it:

```sql
SELECT user_id, city_name FROM table_2
```

In order to solve it you can add it as follows:

```sql
SELECT 
        DISTINCT DATE(create_time) AS date,
        user_id,
        city_name,
        transaction_id,
        price

FROM 
        table_1 a

LEFT JOIN (SELECT _PARTITIONDATE AS pd, user_id, city_name FROM table_2) b 
        ON (a.user_id = b.user_id AND DATE(create_time) = pd)
```

Note that you'll need an alias such as `pd` as it's a pseudocolumn

Probably it was working in the past if you were joining two tables directly such as in (you don't get selectivity benefits in that case):

```sql
FROM 
        table_1 a
LEFT JOIN table_2 b 
        ON (a.user_id = b.user_id AND DATE(create_time) = _PARTITIONDATE)
```

Comment: Hi Guillem, thanks for answering my question. Now I got the idea what I did differently than the previous query that worked out. But, I've tried the way that you suggested and still got the error message `Unrecognized name: _PARTITIONDATE`. Then I tried to get `SELECT user_id, _PARTITIONDATE AS date FROM table_2` and still got the same error message. Is there something that I missed here? Thanks

Comment: And additional information, I'm joining two pseudo-column table in the previous query that worked out, it's different with this case. Should I do something differently?

Comment: Did you also change the `ON` clause to `ON (a.user_id = b.user_id AND DATE(create_time) = b.date)`? It should work even if only one of the tables is partitioned. A simple `SELECT _PARTITIONDATE AS pd FROM table_2` should also work if `table_2` uses [ingestion-time partitioning](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/querying-partitioned-tables#ingestion-time_partitioned_table_pseudo_columns) but not if using [column-based partitioning](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/creating-column-partitions)

Comment: Yes, I do change it to be `ON`. I'll learn about the difference between those two partitioning types. I guess that I'm using the latter, what should I do to get the `_PARTITIONDATE` from the query?

Comment: When you create a partitioned table with the second method you specify a data field (`DATE` or `TIMESTAMP` format) to be used as the partition criteria. Therefore, the additional pseudocolumns are not created as you can query the custom field directly.